# URL Rewrite for Angular 2 App with subresource

Tags: angular, jetty

I have following routes for my angular 2 RC4 app. I am using Jetty and I configured URL rewrites and it works fine for /conferences and /about but when I try /conferences/1234 it gives 404. I see the rewrite url as /index.html/1234. At this point I am not sure whether my rewrite rules are incorrect or something is off in route configuration. Any pointers will be helpful.

Routes -

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '', component: ConferencesComponent },
{ path: 'conferences', component: ConferencesComponent },
{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
{ path: 'conferences/:id', component: ConferenceEditComponent}
```

Rewrite Rules for Jetty -

```
RewritePatternRule oldToNew2 = new RewritePatternRule();
oldToNew2.setPattern("/publicationhubdashboard/conferences");
oldToNew2.setReplacement("/publicationhubdashboard/index.html");
rewrite.addRule(oldToNew2);

RewritePatternRule oldToNew = new RewritePatternRule();
oldToNew.setPattern("/publicationhubdashboard/conferences/*");
oldToNew.setReplacement("/publicationhubdashboard/index.html");
rewrite.addRule(oldToNew);

RewritePatternRule oldToNew1 = new RewritePatternRule();
oldToNew1.setPattern("/publicationhubdashboard/about");
oldToNew1.setReplacement("/publicationhubdashboard/index.html");
rewrite.addRule(oldToNew1);
```

Comment: have you considered using `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: I did try but sub path still had same issue. Does each component need to change for that or just main? I only added changes to main and saw hash after root. This is my very first angular app.